# Set all optional (question mark) types of an interface as never in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to know if there is a way I can create a generic type (something like `NeverOptionals<T>`) such that I can make all optional types on an interface `never` (kind of similar to `Required<T>` but not quite the same).

For example for the following interface:

```js
interface Foo {
    a?: string;
    b: number;
    c: string | undefined;
    d?: number | undefined;
}
```

Using `NeverOptionals<Foo>` would be equivalent to the following interface:

```js
interface FooNeverOptionals {
    a?: never;
    b: number;
    c: string | undefined;
    d?: never;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `[key: string]?: never`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, you can try the following codes. But `{ key?: never }` will also be asserted to `{ key: undefined }`, so I am not sure this is your want.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyycA-AFzIDOYUoA5gNwFEBGFIArgLYvROHIEFarRB1kAH2QcQAEwgxQEWfyKzyVGvX4BfAgTABPAA4oAchABu0APLGwwdCDgAbSgB4AKgD5kAXhxmZABtAAVkUGQAawhDdBhkTwBdClDgBCivABpkUN8IAA9IOUpkACUIAEcOYChldzSM7NzvXxJEsKTkdis+Aj18AxMUTwBGf2QLayg7BydXDwx0b34AelWiZAA9En18BCdqZBhMCjGJvAE2ZFGsoKFkACJHu4E4Cmeg2Q-H-qA)

```js
type NeverOptionals<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Pick<T, P> extends Required<Pick<T, P>> ? T[P] : never;
}
```

If your purpose is to exclude the optional keys, you can try this.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJwD8AXMgM5hSgDmA3PsgEZkgCuAtk9AwQmZWogayAD7I2IACYQYoCFN7IppClVoMAvrlxgAngAcUAOQgA3aAHkDYYOhBwANuQA8AFQB8yALw5GAbQAFZFBkAGsIPXQYZDcAXQBaVUDgBDD3ABpkQK8IAA9IaXJkACUIAEc2YCgFFxS0zOyPLyJYoLjkVnMeXG1dQxQAUTyERzYZUwsody9fbGQgkJBwyOjYwmK3duR8wqlikG6oZFbDqc7suLItwI7NBh19I2Rh0fHrW3snV08fF5GxhMji5JlYbHYHM4Zh5HgNYgBGP6vQEfCHfFwYdAwgD02IICL+8xYyHYXB4yH4aiEInEkhkckOimQmmQQA)

```js
interface Foo {
  a?: string;
  b: number;
  c: string | undefined;
  d?: string;
}

type NeverOptionals<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: Pick<T, P> extends Required<Pick<T, P>> ? T[P] : never;
}

type ExcludeNever<T> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends never ? never : P]: T[P] };


type ExcludOptionals<T> = ExcludeNever<NeverOptionals<T>>

type T1 = ExcludOptionals<Foo>
//   T1 = { b: number; c: string | undefined; }
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of excluding optionals, but after a second thought I think that's exactly what I need. Tysm :)